# fullcalendar popover not big enough when eventLimit used

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I've got a `fullcalendar` using the `eventLimit` feature, but there are so many events that when I click 'more' it scrolls off the calendar and I can't see the events at the bottom.

I need to either get the popover not to be in the calendar or to show past the bottom of the calendar.

Answer (score 5):

You can add a max size to the popover and then set the overflow-y to scroll:

```
<style>
   .fc-more-popover{
       max-height: 200px;
       overflow-y: scroll;
   }
</style>
```